# How to make iframe fit into my parent contenteditable div on pasting?

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I am trying to embed youtube videos in my contenteditable div.The problem is that the iframe already has a width and a height defined beforehand. So it overflows from the div boundaries. I know I can use regex to parse and change the width on pasting the code but I was looking for more reliable solution...Thanks

Here is the code:

```
$('div[contenteditable]').bind("paste", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('hello');
    var text =e.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData('text');
    //do something with text to specify width and height of parent
});
```

Comment: Please include your actual code; just enough to reproduce the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to limit the sizes with by a maximum value you can simply use `max-width: 100%;` and `max-height: 100%;` on the iframe.

JSFiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/2nr0fncg/